# AUC for Multi-Label Classification using SVM

Tags: classification, svm, roc, auc, multilabel

I am tackling a multi-label classification problem and I want to choose a SVM model maximising the AUC. I am not sure if AUC can be used in this case and if yes it is sufficient just to change the parameter probability to probability=True.

This is the python syntax:

```
svm = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)
```